# CodeIgniter web application routes not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3

The company I'm working for have a CodeIgniter web application that is hosted on Hostgator and it is working fine, I've been asked to create a test server and upload the code onto it(btw I'm a laravel coder I don't have any experience in CodeIgniter), so I setup xampp on ubuntu and put the code as the same path as the live server so the only difference is the domain name but I keep getting "Not found" on the test server, for example:

- domain.com/admin will take me to admin/login/signin in live server but on test server I get "The requested URL /admin was not found on this server."
  btw the signin page is located in approot/application/modules/admin/controllers
- domain.com/api/v1/user/inbox_detail in postman will get a 200 response from live server but in test server I get "The requested URL /user/inbox_detail was not found on this server"
  btw user controller is located in approot/application/controllers/api/v1

BUT domain.com/home works fine on both servers which is located in approot/application/controllers

here is the .htaccess file contents:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|
(.*)\.swf|fonts|images|css|less|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

And here is the routes.php contents:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['user'] = 'user';
$route['admin'] = 'admin/Login';
$route['404_override'] = 'page_not_found';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

And here is config.php contents:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
$ask_root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$ask_root .= 
str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $ask_root;
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;
?>
```

Any help is much appreciated it's already taken two days of my life and I'm still stuck.

Comment: What if you put index.php after the domain name and before the controller/method( The other bits ) So on the test server domain.com/index.php/admin/login for example.

Comment: I'm testing to see if mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: yes it worked with index.php as in  domain.com/index.php/admin/login, how can I remove the index.php part? thanks a lot for the help

Comment: It smells like you'll have to enable mod_rewrite for starters... That's easy to look up.